# bootstrap timepicker with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-timepicker

I need to use `Bootstrap TimePicker` with `AngularJS`. I am new to `AngularJS`.

I have edit option for end date. on edit timepicker is shown but not working in `AngularJS`.

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>End Time</label> 
         <span ng-hide="editingViewActivityForm">{{actDetailsData.endTime | date: 'shortTime'}}</span>      
           <div ng-show="editingViewActivityForm" class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input id="timepicker1" ng-model="actDetailsData.endTime" type="text" class="form-control input-small">

<span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="openTime()">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
            </div>
         </div>
```

**Controller**:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.element('#timepicker1').timepicker();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ui-bootstrap` instead of `bootstrap`.

at first download [ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) then add ui bootstrap script and css link to your project .then add `ui.bootstrap` to your module

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

and at the end add datepicker like this :

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" 
 ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"
 datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
 ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
```

[ui bootstrap datepicker in github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepicker)

Comment: Thanks! It is really more exciting. but is there any similar way to use the uib-timepicker with input format.